# Viewing an RSS feed within Sharepoint Services 3.0

Tags: wss-3.0, rss

On our intranet, we've got a small Sharepoint farm running a free instance of WSS 3.0.  We'd really like to add RSS viewers displaying certain feeds on a couple of pages, but I've been told this is not in the base WSS 3.0 package.

We would upgrade, but have been told that our farm will be deprecated and replaced with a corporate solution, eventually, so we can't spend money on anything.

My question is: is there any **free** way we can create an RSS-viewing functionality within the older version of Sharepoint?  Any recs are appreciated, even if they don't pan out.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There was a site called sharepointrss.com I havent checked it in years until now. It appears to have gone away. There is an XML web part you can find in the web part gallery, you may need to add it though. Here is a post on how to use it to display a feed. http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2008/01/02/sharepoint-how-to-display-blog-feed-using-xml-web-part.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.  This was a great solution, and after a lot of effort, I got it working!

Answer (score 0):

Although MOSS 2007 includes an RSS feed web part as standard, you won’t find this functionality on a Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 installation. But, as a work around you can use Cory's suggestion on how to display a feed.