# Displaying a PKI-protected RSS feed within Sharepoint

Tags: wss-3.0, rss, certificate

I'm trying to create a "heartbeat" page in WSS 3.0 that displays multiple RSS feeds from a number of different non-sharepoint sites within our corporate intranet.  Thanks to the help I received here: [Viewing an RSS feed within Sharepoint Services 3.0](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/35854/viewing-an-rss-feed-within-sharepoint-services-3-0) , I was able to get most of the feeds to display.

However, a couple of these RSS feeds require PKI authentication (they verify you have the right access to view them).  If I use the same method (XML viewer web part with XLS formatting), Sharepoint errors out on the RSS pull since it's not passing a certificate.

How can I configure Sharepoint to pass a certificate for these pulls?  Preferably I'd like it to pass the user's own cert, but it might also be okay if it just passes a specific server-owned cert.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authenticated feeds have been an issue from the begining for the web parts provided with SharePoint. Unless you resort to either buying one the enables you to provide/store credentials, or develop your own, you could use search federation capabilities to read external feeds which have the increased advantage of allowing to connect.

Hope will do the trick http://www.thesanitypoint.com/archive/2009/06/12/search-federation-part-2-customizing-results-with-sharepoint-designer.aspx (read twitter as RSS)

or for more details http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/409.search-federation-security-in-microsoft-office-sharepoint-server-2007-en-us.aspx

Comment: This seems like a tougher problem than I expected, with no real standard solution, but your answer was helpful and gave me a deeper understanding of the problem itself.  Thanks.